# Static code analysis in Spyder (Python 3.5) pylint 1.6.4 - on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv3.0, spyder, pylint

I installed Anaconda, and set to Python 3.5 via the following:

```
bash Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
conda install python=3.5
conda update anaconda
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

This gets you Anaconda, Spyder, *and* opencv3.

In looking at using static code analysis, I got some strange results.

A simple program like this:

```
import cv2

# cv2.startWindowThread()
print("Hello there, a simple display.")
image = cv2.imread("clouds.jpg")
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("Over the Clouds", image)
cv2.imshow("Over the Clouds - gray", gray_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

... works OK, and there are no warnings in the Spyder editor, *but*, in doing a static code analysis, it shows some odd messages, with regards to convention and (!) an error, which seems kinda odd.

```
C0325:  4,0: : Unnecessary parens after 'print' keyword
C0111:  1,0: : Missing module docstring
E0401:  1,0: : Unable to import 'cv2'
C0103:  5,0: : Invalid constant name "image"
C0103:  6,0: : Invalid constant name "gray_image"
```

The code runs, I *can* import cv2 (from the command line as well), so what gives?   The error 'Unnecessary parens after 'print' keyword' message makes me think that the checker is looking for stuff in 2.7 format, since the old style print was 'print "Hello there"'...

Doing a 'conda install pylint' shows that it is installed, and is version 1.6.4, for py35_1.

Comment: The first warning (unnecessary parens after 'print' keyword) strongly suggest that you're either running pylint for Python 2 or it's using a ruleset for Python 2. It's kinda hard to diagnose on SO, but make sure you're actually executing the Python 3 version of pylint (because you may have multiple copies installed).

Comment: Yes, that's what I referred to in the last line.   $ pylint --version
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint 1.6.4, 
astroid 1.4.9
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]

Comment: The plot thickens; if you copy the cv2...(long name).so file to cv2.so to the Anaconda3/lib area, the warning on the library goes away.  Still don't know why pylint is trying to check 2.7 syntax.